# В чем ошибка scanner.nextInt();?

Tags: java

Добрый день. Ребята, подскажите что здесь не так?
Вот ошибка

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1    at Main.main(Main.java:25)

```
25 строка: toys[i] = scanner.nextInt();
```

На сортировку не обращайте внимание, я до нее не добираюсь)

Вот код:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int i,j;

    System.out.println("Введите размерность массива: ");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);



    int toys[] = new int[scanner.nextInt()-1];

    System.out.println("Заполните массив данными: ");

    for ( i = 0; i <= toys.length; i++) {

        toys[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Массив упорядоченный по возростанию:");

   for ( i = 0; i < toys.length ; i++) {
        for (int element:toys) {
            int res;
            res = toys[i+1];
            if (res > element){
                toys[i] = res;
                toys[i+1] = element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Спасибо За помощь )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что имеется выход за размеры массива. Длина `toys.length`, к  примеру, 10, отсчет начинается с нуля, последний элемент из 10 в этом случае будет под номером 9.

В цикле `i <= toys.length` вы, следуя вышесказанному примеру, требуете выполнять цикл и тогда, когда `i` сравняется с 10 номером элемента, которого как раз таки нет.

Comment: Благодарствую за объяснение)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for ( i = 0; i <= toys.length; i++) {
> ```

```
for (i = 0; i < toys.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Благодарю, но не пойму логики, ведь i полчается не добегает до конца? Допустим я ввел размерность 3. Цикл щелкает и когда i =2 (образно говоря)  на этом цикл должен закончится ? Правильно ? Потому как i<3 а если i =3  то это условие уже не выполняется ? Правильно?

Comment: @ToysUnderway правильно - цикл "прощелкает" все 3 элемента - 0й, 1й и 2й